# How can I set default groups to put users in when creating them?

Tags: users

When I add an user under Debian Linux, I want to set her default group to a list of specific groups so she will get added to these groups when creating her account.

Comment: On what Unix variant or distribution? Different ones have different commands to manage users and groups.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' sorry, edited question. It's about linux (Debian)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--add_extra_groups` option to the `adduser` command.

If you want the extra groups to be the same for all or most new users, as I interpret your question, you just need to define the `EXTRA_GROUPS` setting in `/etc/adduser.conf`. If you OTOH need a special case for a particular new user, create a new config file, say `/root/adduser.conf`, by copying `/etc/adduser.conf`, add the `EXTRA_GROUPS` setting to the new file, and run `adduser` with the `--conf` and `--add_extra_groups` options.

Comment: No, it's supposed extra groups by default for all new users. Your first option answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
# within the file     /etc/default/useradd

GROUP=100
```

change the id there, 100 corresponds to `users` (in RHEL/CentOS anyway).

With that set, a simple

```
adduser <account name>  --comment <first\ Last_name>   --uid <number>
```

will by default create the given user account having the default group of `GROUP`

modify that user account to have additional groups by doing

```
usermod  <acount name>  -G  <group name>

example:   usermod   ron  -G wheel
           usermod   ron  -G thisgroup,thatgroup,and,so,on
```

to manually re-set an account to have a different default group it is the lowercase `g` option like this

```
usermod <account name>  -g users
```

If you want to create new groups, unless you just want to manually edit `/etc/group` it can be done via

```
groupadd --gid  <new group id>  <new group name>
```

Within `/etc/login.defs` is where `GID_MIN` and `GID_MAX` is set, change those to suit your needs if necessary.